# Fetching data from mysql with play framework using ebean

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

I am trying to fetch data from my mysql server using Play! my approach is like this:

1. in `/application.conf`:

   ```
   db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver    
   db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/CED?characterEncoding=UTF-8"  
   db.default.user="root"  
   db.default.password="root"  
   ebean.default="models.*"
   ```
2. `/models/Budget.java`:

   ```
   package models;

   //imports

   @Entity

   public class Budget extends Model {  
   @Id  
   public String id;

   @Constraints.Required
   public String hauptkategorie;

   public static Model.Finder<String,Budget> find = new Model.Finder<String,Budget>(String.class, Budget.class);

   public static Map<String,String> options() {
       LinkedHashMap<String,String> options = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
       for(Budget c: Budget.find.orderBy("id").findList()) {
           options.put(c.id, c.hauptkategorie);
       }
       System.out.println(options);
       return options;
   }
   }
   ```

And I have a table in CED Database named as budget with 2 columns id, hauptkategorie. When I run the server I get this error `Database 'default' needs evolution!` and tries to apply sql script which creates table.  However, what I want to budget is fetching the data from my DB. Where could be the configuration problem or missing part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must uncomment this property in the application.conf

```
   # Evolutions
   # ~~~~~
   # You can disable evolutions if needed
   evolutionplugin=disabled
```